# Is there a way to set the charset for the WebResource.axd URL?

Tags: .net, webresource

The WebResource URL is currently auto generate by the system, and it look something like this

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=8H_C0aee9xE8e9a-3YoRhA2&amp;t=633413907763620168" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and I need away to set the charset to UTF-8

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=8H_C0aee9xE8e9a-3YoRhA2&amp;t=633413907763620168" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Can this be done in the web.config to tell the system to append it?

Comment: What does the url look like?

Comment: Just fix my original post to show the URL.  Your help is appreciated.